# How to build a conditional branch in Talend if no row was updated in a tMysqlRow?

Tags: talend

In my Talend job I have some xml files. Each of these files contains a field that I will use in the WHERE clause of an UPDATE statement.

I will not describe the whole job and how I've done it, but only the small excerpt: I've modeled this by using a tFileInputXML and a tMysqlRow component.

In the tMysqlRow component I've built an UPDATE query like the following (simplified) one:

```
"UPDATE `my_table`
SET `my_table`.`oneField` = '" + row1.ONEFIELD + "'
WHERE `my_table`.`id` = '" + row1.ID
```

This works fine for me. But I don't understand how to model the exceptionnel case if there will be no updated rows, because the ID wasn't be found in the table. I know that there is a trigger "run if", but I don't how to use it exactly.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a preceding component (**tMap**) that will filter the content of your XML files by defining a *join* between the **ID** column of your **table** and the **ID** column in your **XML**.

Because your main flow (row1) comes from the XML files, you have to reject the rows where the IDs won't be found in the database. That's (one of) the role of tMap component.

You can also have a look on the tJoin component but I haven't used it till now.